# Failed to send Message to remote node

Tags: ignite, apacheignite

I am running my service in local environment and trying to connect to remote node but it showing error failed to send message to remote node.

I want to run my service in local environment and connect it to remote ignite node on different server.

My configuration is:

```java
IgniteConfiguration igniteConfig = new IgniteConfiguration();
igniteConfig.setIgniteInstanceName("MasterCacheCluster");
igniteConfig.setPeerClassLoadingEnabled(true);
igniteConfig.setClientMode(true);
TcpDiscoverySpi discoverySpi = new TcpDiscoverySpi();
TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder ipFinder = new 
TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder();
TcpCommunicationSpi communicationSpi = new 
TcpCommunicationSpi();
     
 
ipFinder.setAddresses(Arrays.asList("server_address:47500..47509"));
discoverySpi.setIpFinder(ipFinder);
igniteConfig.setDiscoverySpi(discoverySpi);
DataStorageConfiguration dataCfg = new 
DataStorageConfiguration();
DataRegionConfiguration rgnCfg = new 
DataRegionConfiguration();
rgnCfg.setName("Sample_Cluster_Region");   
    
rgnCfg.setPageEvictionMode(DataPageEvictionMode.RANDOM_2_LRU);
rgnCfg.setPersistenceEnabled(true);
rgnCfg.setMetricsEnabled(true);
dataCfg.setDataRegionConfigurations(rgnCfg);

Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(igniteConfig);
ignite.cluster().active(true);
System.out.println("Cluster Size: " + 
ignite.cluster().nodes().size());
return ignite;
```

(server address is hidden due to privacy reasons):

```
[13:12:18,839][SEVERE][exchange-worker-#62%MasterCacheCluster%][TcpCommunicationSpi] Failed to send message to remote node [node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=724fff2c-76c2-44e7-921f-b7c37dac7d15, consistentId=7c4ed309-0b9b-40ba-84a1-90384e0940ea, addrs=ArrayList [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, server_address, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=null, discPort=47500, order=1, intOrder=1, lastExchangeTime=1676878928401, loc=false, ver=2.14.0#20220929-sha1:951e8deb, isClient=false], msg=GridIoMessage [plc=2, topic=TOPIC_CACHE, topicOrd=8, ordered=false, timeout=0, skipOnTimeout=false, msg=GridDhtPartitionsSingleMessage [parts=null, partCntrs=null, partsSizes=null, partHistCntrs=null, err=null, client=true, exchangeStartTime=1676878928573, finishMsg=null, super=GridDhtPartitionsAbstractMessage [exchId=GridDhtPartitionExchangeId [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=2, minorTopVer=0], discoEvt=DiscoveryEvent [evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=96f70bd7-cbfb-4a3e-900d-00a93b10d892, consistentId=96f70bd7-cbfb-4a3e-900d-00a93b10d892, addrs=ArrayList [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 127.0.0.1, 172.16.16.50], sockAddrs=HashSet [/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:0, /127.0.0.1:0, LAPTOP-6AUCFF2I/172.16.16.50:0], discPort=0, order=2, intOrder=0, lastExchangeTime=1676878923997, loc=true, ver=2.14.0#20220929-sha1:951e8deb, isClient=true], topVer=2, msgTemplate=null, span=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.tracing.NoopSpan@baed14f, nodeId8=96f70bd7, msg=null, type=NODE_JOINED, tstamp=1676878928556], nodeId=96f70bd7, evt=NODE_JOINED], lastVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=0, order=1676878923547, nodeOrder=0, dataCenterId=0], super=GridCacheMessage [msgId=1, depInfo=null, lastAffChangedTopVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=-1, minorTopVer=0], err=null, skipPrepare=false]]]]]
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to connect to node (is node still alive?). Make sure that each ComputeTask and cache Transaction has a timeout set in order to prevent parties from waiting forever in case of network issues [nodeId=724fff2c-76c2-44e7-921f-b7c37dac7d15, addrs=[/server_address:47100, /[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo]:47100, /127.0.0.1:47100]]
```

Comment: This question doesn't contain personal investigation effort described. Could you please add log messages at least. And it would be nice to have some info about your topology and infrastructure. This one doesn't seem actionable to me right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your client tries to establish [communication](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/clustering/network-configuration#communication) link to the server node with id=`724fff2c-76c2-44e7-921f-b7c37dac7d15` after receiving it's address through [discovery](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/clustering/network-configuration#discovery) protocol. This exception basically implies that there's no connectivity between your local host and `"server_address":47100`. Every single node (including clients) should be visible to the rest of a cluster. My guess is you have some firewall rules or something like that.

Try running some tools to troubleshoot, you could start with.

```bash
nc -vz "server_address" 47100
```

It should be run from your laptop.

It's also worth mentioning that your server expose ipv6 addresses. It's recommended to use [ipv4](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/clustering/network-configuration#ipv4-vs-ipv6) at the moment. Add `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` JVM param to the both client and server JVM start scripts.